# How to use if function in shell scripts?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sftp

I need to use if function to filter out required files only when using SFTP to copy files to my server from a remote server. Here is my try to get the all data inside `/filesnew`.

```
#!/bin/bash


files=`sshpass -p 'XXX' sftp -P 2222 User1@10.18.90.12<<EOF
cd /filesnew
ls
EOF`

files=`echo $files|sed "s/.*sftp> ls//"`



(
  echo cd /filesnew
  for file in $files; do
    echo get $file /data/processedfiles/$file
  done
) |sshpass -p 'XXX' sftp -P 2222 User1@10.18.90.12
```

I need to filter out the files which are starting with `"USER"`.

```
ex:
If($files==*USER*) then
echo get $file /data/processedfiles/$file
```

Can someone show me how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `sftp` to get all files that match the pattern `/filesnew/USER*` (filenames starting with the literal string `USER` in the directory `/filesnew`) and store these locally in the directory `/data/processedfiles`:

```bsh
mkdir -p /data/processedfiles || exit

sftp -P 2222 User1@10.18.90.12 <<'END_SFTP'
get /filesnew/USER* /data/processedfiles
END_SFTP
```

Note that there is no reason to list the files. You also don't have to mention the destination filename on the local host, just the destination directory, and only if it's different from the current directory.

You may skip the initial `mkdir` command if you are confident that the local destination directory always exists.

As an additional note, it may be worth mentioning that `if` is a "reserved word", part of "an `if` statement", and not a function in the shell.